# Using insertBefore and dealing with several nodes of the same name XML PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML which is a catalog containing several `range` nodes which in turn contain several `item` nodes:

```
<cat>
    <range>
        <item>
            <a></a>
            <b></b>
            <c></c>
        </item>
        <item>
            <a></a>
            <b></b>
            <c></c>
        </item>
        <item>
            <a></a>
            <b></b>
            <c></c>
        </item> 
        <item>
            <a></a>
            <b></b>
            <c></c>
        </item>
        <!-- node 'a' need to be added here -->
        <b></b>
        <d></d>
    </range>
    <range>
        <item>
            <a></a>
            <b></b>
            <c></c>
        </item>
        <item>
            <a></a>
            <b></b>
            <c></c>
        </item>
        <!-- node 'a' need to be added here -->
        <b></b>
        <d></d>
    </range>    
</cat>
```

Now I need to add node `a` inside each range just after **ALL** `item` nodes and just before node `b`.

**NOTE:** nodes `a` & `b` inside and outside `item` is the same

I was able to add the `b` node inside `range`, like this:

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagname('range') as $range) {
    forearch ($range->getElementsByTagName('d') as $d) {
        $b = $dom->createElement('b');
        $d = $d->parentNode->insertBefore($b, $d);
    }
}
```

If I use the same code to try and add node `a` outside all the `item` nodes, it won't work since the reference node `b` is the same **inside** and **outside** the `item` nodes; so it will just add node `a` inside the `item` nodes.

I found an `insertAfter` function;

```
function insertAfter(\DOMNode $newNode, \DOMNode $referenceNode)
{
  if($referenceNode->nextSibling === null) {
      return $referenceNode->parentNode->appendChild($newNode);
  } else {
      return $referenceNode->parentNode->insertBefore($newNode, $referenceNode->nextSibling);
  }
}
```

but it will not give me the desired result since if I used `item` as the reference node, it will add the new node just after the first `item` whereas I need it after **all** the `item` nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve what you are trying to do is by using xPath.

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$bs = $xpath->query("//range/b");
$a = new DOMElement('a');

foreach ($bs as $b) {
    $b->parentNode->insertBefore($a, $b);
}
```

This gets alls the "b" that are a direct child of range but not its grandchildren.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the first level children compare until find the one you want (`$b`) and insert before it:

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagname('range') as $range) {
    foreach($range->childNodes as $first_level_child) {
        if($first_level_child->tagname=='b') {
            $a = $dom->createElement('a');
            $first_level_child->parentNode->insertBefore($a, $first_level_child);
        }
    }
}
```